# How to add a date to a datepicker which will never expire

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with HTML and AngularJS. I want to add a date to datepicker which will never expire: like `99/99/9999`. I'm able to read this date from controller and I'm able to set the date in controller.

Comment: There is no such date as 99/99/9999. There are only 12 months in a year, and at most there are 31 days in a month. Maybe that's the problem. If you try using 01/01/9999 instead of 99/99/9999, does it work? Also, how far into the future does the date really need to be? I'm guessing 500 years is enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: A date will expire, you can't change the universe. Even `99/99/9999` Alpha Centauri.

Comment: You don't need to worry about expiry of date.. your software is going to rewrite after atmost 5/10 years approx....

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, maybe using `yearRange` in datepicker, where you can set year range.

> Default value: “-10:+10″

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
    changeYear:true,
    yearRange: "2016:9999"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd  hh:ii" type="text" id="date" value="">
```

Comment: This is working but it does not fix the users problem. We need kind of a wormhole to solve the users problem.